# how to change the jasper report textfield markup property value dynamically in java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I wanted to change the `text field` `markup` property value of `jasper report` in run time of java application.

Without modifying/recompile the jasper file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For current feature, its impossible to change textfield markup value in java application. But there is a trick that u might want to try.

First, textfield markup have 4 fixed options which is `none`, `rtf`, `html`, `styled`. U can pass parameter from java app to change markup property value let say `markupValue`.

In Jasper, u need to create 4 different textfield with different markup value as i mention above. At each Texfield `Print When Expression`, u need to compare value parameter `markupValue` that u pass from java app.

`$P{markupValue}.equals("rtf")` will display textfield with markup value rtf and so on.